# What does hate mean in Luke 14:26?

Tags: luke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jesus' command to hate your father and mother in Luke 14:26](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/57/jesus-command-to-hate-your-father-and-mother-in-luke-1426)

> Luke 14:26 If anyone comes to me and does not hate his father and
>   mother, his wife and children, his brothers and sisters--yes, even his
>   own life--he cannot be my disciple.

I've been told that the original word in Greek does not mean hatred but loving less. And that it was translated as such because there's no equivalent word in English.

Is this understanding correct? What is the original intent of the text as stated in Greek?

Comment: @JonEricson Yes they do. Especially matiu's answer on the meaning of Greek. Hold on I will delete it.

Comment: No need.  It's just a dup that will help future seekers. ;-)  Your title is much better.